# Is my GPU going bad? GeForce GT 620M

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, gpu

I've got an issue on my laptop and I think it might be the GPU.
It is a GeForce GT 620M (1Gb) and it started to make funny shapes on the rendering of polygons in apps that use the GPU.

Here is a link of the video sample.

[Imgur Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7X4B.jpg)

Are there any tools that I can run to get a definitive answer that something is not good?

Comment: It's bad. If that happens only on applications that needs GPU (games) your GPU is slowly dying.

Comment: Yeah, all other apps seem ok. When I look under the NVidia settings panel, the spinning NVidia logo also seems to break the polygons.

Comment: By all other apps do you mean that only this one particula game exhibits this problem and **everything** else is fine, or is it only games that do this or is it any 3D application that does it?

Comment: Have you tried to update gpu driver? If you have the most current version of driver, try to reinstall it and if it won't help try to downgrade to (one) version older driver. Did it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GPU is definitely the problem, but there are things you can try.

- Uninstall and reinstall the most recent version of the nVidia Forceware drivers.  If you have already done this, try removing them and installing an older version, ideally the version that worked for you before.
- The 620m is a mobile card.  If the above doesn't bear fruit, it may be because laptop manufacturers *do not always use a reference card design* for integrating the GPU.  This means that the chipset itself may be on a custom board from the manufacturer.  If so, try the same process, but only use the newest drivers available from *your laptop manufacturer*. There are cases where universal drivers do not apply properly to laptops for this reason.
- Ensure that there is no blockage in your cooling for your computer, and put it on a cooling pad.  Graphical artifacts can occur if the video card overheats.  Most likely, the video adapter chip itself is passively cooled by a large heatsink inside the case that also has cooling pipes which snake across the CPU heatsink.  This means heat is a unified problem across the case, and if cooling is bad for any component, it's bad on the GPU.

Outside of these, you don't have a lot of options.   The downside to laptops is the difficulty in servicing them, even if it's a custom unit like a Sager, Clevo, or shop build. From here, your best bet is to contact the manufacturer and request service if you are in warranty, but anything with a 620m is probably way out of warranty.  I had a card from that generation in a laptop almost a decade ago.

Comment: Good point about using laptop vendor drivers.  They are often proprietary

Comment: Hi, so I uninstalled the NVidia drivers and did a clean install with the NVidia drivers from Acer. Seems to have resolved itself for now. Hopefully it was just that, bad drivers and not a dying GPU. Although it might still fail!

Comment: That probably fixed it.  I had the same thing happen with an Inspiron with an nVidia card once, and it only would work with Dell drivers.